# SQL Server 2016 Deadlock

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, deadlock

I want to validate my understanding of the sqlserver deadlock report:

- context:

```
parent_table(id); 
child_table(parent_id, col1, col2, ...);

constraint primary_key(id) on parent_table;
constraint primary_key(parent_id, col1) "pk_child_table" on child_table; 
constraint foreign_key(parent_id) references parent_tabl on delete cascade
```

- sqlserver 2016
- isolation level: READ COMMITTED
- given deadlock report:

```
<deadlock>
    <victim-list>
        <victimProcess id="process1"/>
    </victim-list>
    <process-list>
        <process id="process1" taskpriority="0" logused="884" waitresource="KEY: 6:72057594911457280 (32da7da6dc73)"
                 waittime="4320" ownerId="73322515021" transactionname="implicit_transaction"
                 lasttranstarted="2024-02-20T07:31:23.417" XDES="0x1d38e169900" lockMode="RangeS-U" schedulerid="40"
                 kpid="6240" status="suspended" spid="336" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2"
                 lastbatchstarted="2024-02-20T07:31:23.447" lastbatchcompleted="2024-02-20T07:31:23.447"
                 lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.447" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server"
                 hostname="node1.host.com" hostpid="0" loginname="dbuser" isolationlevel="read committed (2)"
                 xactid="73322515021" currentdb="6" currentdbname="dbname" lockTimeout="4294967295"
                 clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="24" stmtend="116"
                       sqlhandle="0x02000000c98f681b852f2b5ac263e52bb2d8019412d0c7470000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
                    unknown
                </frame>
                <frame procname="unknown" line="1"
                       sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
                    unknown
                </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>(@P0 bigint)delete from parent_table where id=@P0</inputbuf>
        </process>
        <process id="process2" taskpriority="0" logused="884" waitresource="KEY: 6:72057594911457280 (b6ebcc0466d0)"
                 waittime="4290" ownerId="73322515432" transactionname="implicit_transaction"
                 lasttranstarted="2024-02-20T07:31:23.423" XDES="0x1db05a07900" lockMode="RangeS-U" schedulerid="7"
                 kpid="12444" status="suspended" spid="209" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2"
                 lastbatchstarted="2024-02-20T07:31:23.447" lastbatchcompleted="2024-02-20T07:31:23.447"
                 lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.447" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server"
                 hostname="node2.host.com" hostpid="0" loginname="dbuser" isolationlevel="read committed (2)"
                 xactid="73322515432" currentdb="6" currentdbname="dbname" lockTimeout="4294967295"
                 clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="24" stmtend="116"
                       sqlhandle="0x02000000c98f681b852f2b5ac263e52bb2d8019412d0c7470000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
                    unknown
                </frame>
                <frame procname="unknown" line="1"
                       sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
                    unknown
                </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>(@P0 bigint)delete from parent_table where id=@P0</inputbuf>
        </process>
    </process-list>
    <resource-list>
        <keylock hobtid="72057594911457280" dbid="6" objectname="dbname.dbo.child_table" indexname="pk_child_table"
                 id="lock1b7c8d5cf00" mode="RangeS-U" associatedObjectId="72057594911457280">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="process2" mode="RangeS-U"/>
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="process1" mode="RangeS-U" requestType="wait"/>
            </waiter-list>
        </keylock>
        <keylock hobtid="72057594911457280" dbid="6" objectname="dbname.dbo.child_table" indexname="pk_child_table"
                 id="lock1ba79447380" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594911457280">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="process1" mode="X"/>
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="process2" mode="RangeS-U" requestType="wait"/>
            </waiter-list>
        </keylock>
    </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

- I'm struggling to understand how one process can obtain a range lock for update (RangeS-U) that includes index key A, while another process owns an exclusive lock (X) on the same index key A? Shouldn't holding e.g. a X lock on index key A prevent a RangeS-U on key A being obtained, and vice-versa?
- Is my understand correct that: `waitresource` hash (`(32da7da6dc73)` vs `(b6ebcc0466d0)`) is different for the 2 processes, so they're trying to lock on different rows?
- Given 2 processes concurrently deleting the same `parent_table` record that has `child_table` records that are to be cascade deleted, and that there is a primary key on the `child_table` (meaning there is index on it)... Under what scenarios would this deadlock ever happen?

EDIT: add example data

```
parent_table:
-------------
id
1
2

child_table:
------------
parent_id | col_1 | ...
1         | "A"   | ...
2         | "A"   | ...
...

2 threads:
1st thread is `DELETE FROM parent_table where id = 1`
2nd thread is `DELETE FROM parent_table where id = 2`
```

child_table has:

- composite primary key of (parent_id, col_1)
- fk `parent_id` references parent_table with `ON DELETE CASCADE`

Answer (score 0):

Your index key A is composite key: `(parent_id, col1)` so for one parent id you have multiple rows, in my picture suppose you want to delete rows with parent_id = 1, you have at least 4 rows, one process started with (1,5) and the second from (1,2).

[image]

Comment: wouldn't process-2 's RS-U be over (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5) ?

Comment: But i guess it would be hard to implement a range lock over a composite key such as this without a second level of indirection, probably like 1 -> [(1, 2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5)], 2 -> ...?

Comment: @brownsugarpearl I think this situation is only possible with parallel plan as there is no reason to scan the index in different order in different sessions, so the range is not all inclusive for the entire index but only for a subset  that belongs to some single thread.

Comment: hi @sepupic thanks for your explanation. I've added more context in the question, hopefully that could add insight. I'm not understanding "so the range is not all inclusive for the entire index but only for a subset that belongs to some single thread"

Comment: hi @brownsugarpearl, what I said is different from your "2 threads:
1st thread is `DELETE FROM parent_table where id = 1`
2nd thread is `DELETE FROM parent_table where id = 2`", I meand there is 2 sessions, not 2 threads, and every session that executes in parallel for example executes on 4 threads, ok? The overall work is divided between 4 threads and every thread aquires locks only ot its portion of data, that's why you don't have 1 range but 4 ranges per session

Comment: @brownsugarpearl you can find more on parallelism here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5404/parallelism-in-sql-server-execution-plan/#:~:text=The%20parallelism%20concept%20comes%20from,together%20into%20one%20final%20result.

Comment: thanks thats clear. However, I can't seem reproduce the problem. I'm running JDBC, multiple threads all trying to delete at the same time. Does sqlserver differentiate between sessions  from threads vs processes? Also, I've verified the  maxdop is 0 and so is cost threshold for parallelism - Is there some other settings in particular that i need to set to get the problem to show its ugly head?

Comment: @brownsugarpearl I've seen similar situation on my server with JDBC, our developers use SPRING, they just open 1 outer transaction where make more than 1 delete, so their transactions can have for example delete where id = 1; delete where id = 2; delete where id = 3 all inside 1 transaction and another session does delete where id = 4 delete where id = 3 delete where id = 2 they don't use begin tran but they have IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS on.